# How can I adjust 3-D bar grouping and y-axis labeling in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, label, bar-chart

I have a 3D plot like this:

[image]

On the y-axis of the plot, each group of three bars refers to the same parameters: x1, x2, x3. I would like to have a spacing on the y-axis for each group of three bars, so that it becomes more clear that those bars are referring to the same parameters. At the same time, I would like to put a label on the y-axis for each group of three bars. For example, the following label layout for the y-axis would be desired:

```
x1 x2 x3   x1 x2 x3   x1 x2 x3
  grid1     grid2      grid3
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome! The code that I used to plot the bars is given below:

```
Z = rand(9,5);
h = bar3(Z);
[r c] = size(Z);

zdata = [];
for i = 1:c
    zdata = [];
    for j = 1:r
        zdata = [zdata; ones(6,4)*Z(j,i)];
    end
set(h(i),'Cdata',zdata)
end
colormap
colorbar
set(gca,'YTickLabel',['x1';'x2';'x3';'x1';'x2';'x3';'x1';'x2';'x3']);
view([-64 44]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add spacing in between your groups of bars by specifying an additional input to [`bar3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) indicating the positions at which to place the columns of bars along the y axis. You can also plot additional text in your axes using the function [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html):

```
Z = rand(9, 5);              % Some random sample data
[r, c] = size(Z);            % Size of Z
Y = [1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11];   % The positions of bars along the y axis
C = mat2cell(kron(Z, ones(6, 4)), 6*r, 4.*ones(1, c)).';  %' Color data for Z

hBar = bar3(Y, Z);           % Create the bar graph
set(hBar, {'CData'}, C);     % Add the color data
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', {'x1' 'x2' 'x3'});  % Modify the y axis tick labels
view(-70, 30);               % Change the camera view
colorbar;                    % Add the color bar
text(-2, 2, 'grid1');        % Add "grid1" text
text(-2, 6, 'grid2');        % Add "grid2" text
text(-2, 10, 'grid3');       % Add "grid3" text
```

[image]

Note that you may have to adjust the x and y values of your text objects to get them to render where you want for the given camera view that you choose.

**EDIT:**

If you'd also like to display the values above each bar, you can do that by adding the following to the above code:

```
hText = text(kron((1:c).', ones(r, 1)), ...    %' Column of x values
             repmat(Y(:), c, 1), ...            % Column of y values
             Z(:)+0.05, ...                     % Column of z values
             num2str(Z(:)), ...                 % Text strings
             'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');  % Center the strings
```

It should be pointed out that having this much plotted text gets a little messy, since some of the text will be overlapping or hidden behind the bars. The text is also a bit redundant, since the *color* of the bars is really meant to show the values.

Comment: +1 I think some kind of gradual colormap would look better: `colormap(flipud(summer))`

Comment: @Amro: Yeah, a different colormap would look better. I was just trying to reproduce the original figure with the modifications the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! I also need to plot at the top of each bar, the value associated to it (coming from Z). I was doing sth. like:
    h=text(mymat(:,1),mymat(:,2)-0.20,Z(:),num2str(Z(:)));
where mymat is used as a matrix of indexes. Do you know, if there's a more efficient way to do that? In my case, I filled 'mymat' as:

    rows=5;cols=9;

    mymat=zeros(rows*cols,2);
    k=1;
    for j=1:rows
        for i=1:cols
            mymat(k,1) = j;
            mymat(k,2) = i;
            k = k + 1;
        end
    end


Best wishes

Comment: @Javier: I updated my answer to show you another way to add the text you want, although it does make the plot harder to read.

Comment: @gnovice, do you mind in illustrating how to change the range on the z-axis? for instance, to display the bars in the value range from [0.15,1], instead of from [0,1]. I tried to use ZLim([zmin zmax]); but the format of the 3D bar was completely loose.

Comment: @Tin: What do you mean "completely loose"? Are you wanting to *not* display parts of the bars that are below 0.15?

Comment: @gnovice, exactly, I would like not to display the parts of the bars below 0.15.

Comment: @Tin: It's tricky, but one way to do it is to: 1) Replace the line where the bar graph is created with `hBar = bar3(Y, max(Z-0.15, 0));`, which shrinks the Z data. 2) Add the line `set(gca, 'ZTickLabel', get(gca, 'ZTick')+0.15, 'ZTickMode', 'manual')` to change the tick labels on the Z axis accordingly. 3) If you want to remove bars with zero height, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050658/52738) I gave to another question.

Comment: I have very similar question: How can I make some grids on both y-axis and x-axis?

Comment: Folks these are different questions: don't bury these new questions in comments...