# Grouping bar3 plots like bar

Tags: matlab, 3d, bar-chart

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the same grouping behavior of `bar` plots into `bar3`.
For example, if you plot

```
  bar(rand(3));
```

you get 3 bars for each point; `bar` groups the different *y* values for each *x*. Now I would like to do the same with a 3D data. That is that I have several slices of 2D data that I want to visualize as groups of bars. Then, if my data is

```
data = rand(3,3,2);
```

I would like to see `data(1,1,:)` as a group of bars, and `data(1,2,:)` as another group and so on.

Is it possible? I cannot find a way of achieving this.

**Edit:** I'm adding more details, to explain it better.

Lets said that we have two, or more, sets of data `{x_(i,j)^s}`. What I need is to group in the same grid position `(i,j)`, all the sets `s`. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601434/3d-bar-and-y-axis-labeling), they are grouping the data sets side by side, not element-wise, like this:

```
x1(s1) x1(s2) x1(s3)   x2(s1) x2(s2) x2(s3)   x3(s1) x3(s2) x3(s3)
x4(s1) x4(s2) x4(s3)   x5(s1) x5(s2) x5(s3)   x6(s1) x6(s2) x6(s3)
x7(s1) x7(s2) x7(s3)   x8(s1) x8(s2) x8(s3)   x9(s1) x9(s2) x9(s3)
```

I would like the `bar` command behavior, it tends to group when putting more than one data set. I would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: [This duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601434/3d-bar-and-y-axis-labeling) addresses how to group 3-D bar plots.

Comment: Although they are addressing the grouping, I need to group all the x_1, x_2, and x_3 together, in the same grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understood, but if you are looking for grouped behavior like you mention with `bar(rand(3))` then you can try

```
figure; bar3(rand(5),'grouped');
% or maybe
figure; bar3(rand(5),'stacked');
```

or try to rearrange the data in data so it can work better with bar3 with reshape:

```
data = rand(3,3,2);
% now each data(i, j, :) will be in single row 
changeddata = reshape(data , [size(data , 1)*size(data , 2) 2]);
figure; bar3(changeddata);
figure; bar3(changeddata ,'grouped');
figure; bar3(changeddata ,'stacked');
```

Maybe if you can give a code example for how it's supposed to look in one group, it would help to understand your question better.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I don't know how to generate that kind of graph... to show you.. I would like something like this: {+.-} {+.-} {+.-} group in one line and then {+.-} {+.-} {+.-} other set of data grouped in the next line, where '+' '.' and '-' are the data values, in that case I have 3 set of data, e.g., `rand(2,3,3)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group bars in 3D bar plots, but you are happy o small groups (let's say 2 or 3 bars each group) then you can simply take advantage of the Y argument in bar3:
BAR3(Y,Z,WIDTH)
so you specify the location of the two groups of bars with two shifted Y vectors.

example: 
 bar3(0:3:9,rand(4,4),0.3)
 hold on
 bar3(1:3:10,rand(4,4),0.3)

then you can edit the label the way it suits you.