# To represent the two 2-D matrices in a single bar graph plot

Tags: matlab, figure

I do have generated two 2-D dimensional matrices from my core process. Now, I want to represent them via the bar graphs. 
I could manage to get the 3d bar graph for independant matrix as shown in figures attached.

[image: xData bar3 figure]

My data matrices are

1. "xData" - size is :  (52 x 46 )
2. "yData" - size is : (52 x 46)

**They'll always have the same size.**

Now, I want to represent them together in *'Grouped Style'*  As show in [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html). I got the 3D dimensional matrix by combining them (xData and yData) together i.e. generated 52 x 46 x 2 matrix and then tried to plot with *bar3* command; but, I got an error and couldn't plot.
Do you guys have any idea on  how to do it ?

Comment: Can you provide us the exact Matlab code you used to create the showed graph and the code you tried with the exact error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping bar3 plots like bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334088/grouping-bar3-plots-like-bar)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do that using a loop and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991376/how-to-set-x-and-y-values-when-using-bar3-in-matlab):

```
% generate random data
sz = [5 4];
xData = rand(sz);
yData = rand(sz);
% plot zeros in the same size to prepare plot
Z = zeros(sz);
h0 = bar3(Z);
set(h0,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','none');
axis tight
% plot each data column in a loop
hold on
for kk = 1:size(xData,2)
    h1 = bar3([xData(:,kk),yData(:,kk)],'grouped');
    % move current bars to their x position
    cellfun(@(x) set(h1,'XData', x + (kk - 1)), get(h1,'XData'));
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user2999345  looks like it would do the needful.. will update you accordingly