# Getting a second row of xlabels in matlab graph?

Tags: matlab

How do I get a row of labels underneath my `xticklabel`?
ie patient 1, 2 3 4?

[image]
This shows how to get the grouped labels but I can't quite work it out for this example :
[How can I adjust 3-D bar grouping and y-axis labeling in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601434/how-can-i-adjust-3-d-bar-grouping-and-y-axis-labeling-in-matlab)

Comment: You will have to do it manually with `text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, the usage of the function `text()` will be as follows:

```
text(3,-.1,'Patient1');
text(10,-.1,'Patient2');
```

The first number is x-coordinate in axis units and the second one is y-coordinate. Thus, the sign minus stands to denote that the position of the text is below the axis.