# Plotting Distributions(Histogram) on map

Tags: python, google-maps, gis, visualization

I have data in the format (latitude, longitude, value). I want to plot (lat, long) -> value on a map of the city. Something like the following images: 
[image]
[image]

I've already tried the following:

1. Python's Matplotlib: Unable to find required functions
2. Plotly
3. [r-barplots on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465070/barplots-on-a-map), RG-histogram-bar-chart-over-map.
4. [plot-3d-bars-on-a-map-in-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539247/plot-3d-bars-on-a-map-in-matlab): This will do, but I'm trying to find a similar thing in python
5. [D3 map histogram](https://vida.io/documents/s5qo5Gwrct5HNxAD2): This allows me to plot
   city-wise, but not within a city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted above question and then, found interesting plotting libraries.

[Cesium](https://cesium.com/platform/cesiumjs/) : An open-source JavaScript library for 3D globes and maps.

[ArcGIS](https://www.arcgis.com/features/index.html): This one is paid (60 days free trial is available), but provide a wide variety of beautiful visualizations on 2D maps and 3D globes

Answer (score 0):

How about [Basemap](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html)?
It is a matplotlib extension, so it has got all its features to create data visualizations and adds the geographical projections and some datasets to be able to plot coastlines, countries directly from the library.

[image]