# Hide zero values (counts) in hist3 plot

Tags: matlab, graphics, histogram

You can hide [zero values in a bar3 plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050367/how-to-hide-zero-values-in-bar3-plot-in-matlab), but that solution is **not directly applicable** to [`hist3()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/hist3.html) even though the workaround is similar in fashion.

Here's a workaround based on [`imdilate()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) which requires the Image Processing TB and I would like to see **suggestions** that are **Toolbox independent** (only Stats TB is ok).

```
% Example graph
hist3([2 0; 0 1; 1 1],[2 2])
```

[image]

```
% handle to graph3d.surfaceplot
h = get(gca,'child');

% retrieve the heights
heights       = get(h,'Zdata');

% Index outer heights leaving a contour of zeros
mask          = ~logical(imdilate(heights,ones(3)));

% Set the zero heights to NaN
heights(mask) = NaN;

% Final result
set(h,'ZData',heights)
```

[image]

Here's what happens to `heights`:

```
heights =...
    [0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
mask =...
    [1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1]
heights =...
  [NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0     0     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0     1     1     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0     1     1     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0     0     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     0     0     0     0   NaN     0     0     0     0   NaN
     0     1     1     0   NaN     0     1     1     0   NaN
     0     1     1     0   NaN     0     1     1     0   NaN
     0     0     0     0   NaN     0     0     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN]
```

Comment: funny thing, I started to investigate this but ended up with a solution to the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17477348/97160 . It wasnt until I was done that I realized you were using `hist3` not `bar3` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `imdilate(height, ones(3))` with

```
filter2(ones(3), height)
```

or

```
conv2(ones(3), height, 'same')
```

and neither require a toolbox.

Comment: +1 Now that you mention, I remembered also `conv2(height,ones(3),'same')`. If you include it in your answer I will wait a bit for other answers and accepts the best.